# If the only two empirical measurements we can make are change in length and passage of time, how are dimensions and units of quantities formulated?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, thought-experiment, foundations

So this is something really confusing to me. Recently a professor of mine gave a talk and said something that I thought was very interesting and kind of crazy. "The only two quantitative measurements we can make are, changes in length - in multiple dimensions - and passage of time. With these two different forms of measurement people have come up with all of Physics."

At first I was not convinced and the first thing that came to mind was mass and maybe electric/magnetic quantities, but then when I looked at how we measure them, it is indeed just a change in length on some scale and passage of time. So how did the formulations of dimensions and units come about?

Answer (score 0):

Mass is indeed a separate fundamental property. But the professor's point is that mass has been *measured* by means of displacements and durations. Mass is defined as total force per acceleration, both of which are derived properties that arrive from length and time.